# How can I Use an external Fuction without using extra classes in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently working on quite a big Program and want to kind of "outsource" some of my less important functions to separate files.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and it only provides me the possibility of creating new classes, or new resources. I just want to create an extra .cpp and an .h belonging to this .cpp and then import them in my main application.

I imagine it in an hierachy like this (in VS2015):

```
Solution "TheBigProgramAlpha" (1 project):
[+]TheBigProgram
    (...)

    [0] HeaderFiles
        -stdafx.h
        -targetver.h
        -resource.h
        [0] MySeparatedFunctions
            -firstFile.h
            -secondFile.h

    [0] SourceFiles
        -TheBigProgram.cpp
        [0] MySeparatedFunctions
            -firstFile.cpp
            -secondFile.cpp
```

In my TheBigProgram.cpp I want to call  #include "firstFile.h"  and then be able to use those functions in the firstFile.h and firstFile.cpp in the same way I did before.

My Problem is that I apparently have to crate an extra class, create an object of this class and only THEN can use my separated functions when called from this new object. I don't want to do that since some of the functions use other functions that remained in the main file and would all have to be adapted.

Is there a simple way of adding an extra file to my TheBigProgram project without creating extra classes? Or how could I split my TheBigProgram.cpp?

Comment: Just because VS only lets you "make a new class" doesn't mean you have to leave the boilerplate they add. The thing that makes it a new class is the class definition in the file, not the fact that it's a new file. Just "make a new class" and then replace whatever is in those files with whatever you want and import them however you like.

Comment: @Termhn And I could just call the Functions defined in there if i just include the header? Or do I need to include the cpp as well?

Comment: @VTT If I do that the new file doesnt appear in my hierachy, and If I create a new Class and empty it out is does! :O Even after I saved it in the correct place

Comment: "I just want to create an extra .cpp and an .h belonging to this .cpp" and what exactly prevents you from doing this? Right click on project in Solution Explorer -> Add -> New item.